# Proving tautology by substitution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How do I prove whether the following statement is a tautology or not using substitution?
∃x,P(x)∧∃x,Q(x)⇒∃x,(P(x)∧Q(x))

From what I understood if the expression is of the form A⇒A, then we can substitute values to prove tautology.
But how can I interpret  ∃x,P(x) and ∃x,Q(x) on the RHS. Does this mean P∧Q?  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't believe this is true. Let P(x) be the statement x is even and Q(x) that x is odd. There certainly exists and even number and an odd number, but no number that is both odd and even.

Comment: Yes,this is not true,but I am looking for a proof using substitution and not worrying about the truth value so much

Comment: If you know that the formula is not *valid* (better than : a *tautology*), to prove this fact you have to "manufacture" a counterexample, i.e. a *domain* and an interpretation for $P$ and $Q$ such that the antecedent is *true* and the consequent is *false*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the *validity* of a *first-order* formula $\varphi$ by *substitution*, you have to start from a propositional *tautology* $\alpha$, like $A \to A$ in your example, and find a suitable **uniform** substitution such that, when applied to $\alpha$, will produce $\varphi$.

Here the key-word is "uniform", i.e. every instance of a propositional letter $A_i$ occurring in $\alpha$ must be replaced with the same "atom".

Thus, form $A \to A$ we can get :

- $\exists x P(x) \to \exists x P(x)$, or
- $(∃x P(x) ∧ ∃x Q(x)) \to (∃x P(x) ∧ ∃x Q(x))$

but **never** :

> $(∃x P(x) ∧ ∃x Q(x)) \to ∃x(P(x) ∧ Q(x))$.